# Reduce an expression where the variables can assume only $\pm 1$

Tags: equation-solving, number-theory

I would like to solve this equation:

```
x1y1 + x2y2 + x3y3 + x4y4 = 0
```

and I would like to count the number of distict solutions.
Here $x_1,\dots,x_4$ and $y_1,\dots,y_4$ can be only $\pm1$.
How can I do? Thank you in advance. I tried this:

```
Reduce[x1*y1 + x2*y2 + x3*y3 + x4*y4 == 0, {x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y3, y4}, Integers]
```

But of course it returns every possible integer solution to this kind of diophantine equation.

Comment: You could always brute-force the thing: `signs = Tuples[{1, -1}, 4]; 2 * Length[Flatten[Table[If[signs[[j]] . signs[[k]] == 0, {j, k}, Nothing], {j, Length[signs]}, {k, j}], 1]]`, but I'm sure there's a more clever approach.

Comment: The condition $x = \pm 1$ is equivalent to the equation $x^2 = 1$, maybe you can use that?

Comment: `With[{u={x1,x2,x3,x4},v={y1,y2,y3,y4}},Solve[{u.v==0,u^2==1,v^2==1},Join[u,v]]]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could just add the appropriate constraints. I set this up programmatically to save wear and tear on my four typing fingers.

```
xvars = Array[x, 4];
yvars = Array[y, 4];
allvars = Join[xvars, yvars];
eqn = xvars . yvars == 0;
constraints = Map[#^2 - 1 == 0 &, allvars];
allsolns = Reduce[Join[{eqn}, constraints], allvars];
Length[allsolns]
allsolns[[1 ;; 5]]

(* Out[361]= 96

Out[362]= (x[1] == -1 && x[2] == -1 && x[3] == -1 && x[4] == -1 && 
   y[1] == -1 && y[2] == -1 && y[3] == 1 && 
   y[4] == 1) || (x[1] == -1 && x[2] == -1 && x[3] == -1 && 
   x[4] == -1 && y[1] == -1 && y[2] == 1 && y[3] == -1 && 
   y[4] == 1) || (x[1] == -1 && x[2] == -1 && x[3] == -1 && 
   x[4] == -1 && y[1] == -1 && y[2] == 1 && y[3] == 1 && 
   y[4] == -1) || (x[1] == -1 && x[2] == -1 && x[3] == -1 && 
   x[4] == -1 && y[1] == 1 && y[2] == -1 && y[3] == -1 && 
   y[4] == 1) || (x[1] == -1 && x[2] == -1 && x[3] == -1 && 
   x[4] == -1 && y[1] == 1 && y[2] == -1 && y[3] == 1 && y[4] == -1) *)
```

Answer (score 7):

If you just want the count:

```
Count[Tuples[{-1, 1}, 8], v_ /; v[[1 ;; 4]] . v[[5 ;; 8]] == 0]
(*    96    *)
```

or with a more explicit criterion:

```
Count[Tuples[{-1, 1}, 8],
      {x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, y1_, y2_, y3_, y4_} /; x1*y1 + x2*y2 + x3*y3 + x4*y4 == 0]
(*    96    *)
```

If you want the actual solutions in the form $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4\}$:

```
Select[Tuples[{-1, 1}, 8], #[[1 ;; 4]] . #[[5 ;; 8]] == 0 &]
(*    {{-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1}, {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1},
      ...
       {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1}}    *)
```